# @mixin scss with nested elements is possible?

Tags: css, sass, nested, element

I'm trying to use a mixin to make the code less repetitive, but I can't reach the nested elements.

Could anyone tell me if this approach is possible?

```
@mixin schema-calendar($backgroundColor: var(--ion-color-primary), $titleColor: var(--ion-color-secondary)) {
  background-color: $backgroundColor !important;

  .switch-btn,  
  ion-icon {
    color: $titleColor !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .week-toolbar li {
    color: $titleColor !important;
    font-weight: 900;
  }
  button.today p { color: $titleColor !important; }
  button.on-selected {
    p { color: var(--ion-color-secondary-contrast) !important;}
  }
}

ion-calendar.schemaDefault {
  @include schema-calendar();
}

ion-calendar.schemaBlackRed {
  @include schema-calendar(var(--ion-card-black-red));
}

ion-calendar.schemaIndigo {
  @include schema-calendar(var(--ion-card-indigo), var(--ion-color-light));
}
```

When used directly in css it works perfectly, I know that when scss is compiled to css the code is modified but the result is the same, but when I use the mixin according to the code above, only the background-color property is applied.

```
ion-calendar.schemaBlackRed {
  // primaryColor: 'var(--ion-card-blackred)', secondaryColor: 'var(--ion-color-secondary)', titleColor: 'var(--ion-color-secondary)',
  background-color: var(--ion-card-black-red) !important;

  .switch-btn,  
  ion-icon {
    color: var(--ion-color-secondary) !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .week-toolbar li {
    color: var(--ion-color-secondary) !important;
    font-weight: 900;
  }
  button.today p { color: var(--ion-color-secondary) !important; }
  button.on-selected {
    p { color: var(--ion-color-secondary-contrast) !important;}
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try ? It sure works. When you need to test something like this, you can use [SassMeister Playground](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the information, I validated it by the tool and the code is really correct, but for some reason it doesn't work as expected and without the mixin it works perfectly, still trying to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was occurring because I had included the style at the page level, moved the code from the initial Ionic load and everything worked as expected.